# I lost my android key store

Tags: android, android-keystore

I did not properly create the keys, where he is now?

I created the keys, where I create the application

[image]

**where keys is now?**   (there is only one file LM.apk, but he did not keys)

[image]

Comment: No, there is only one file LM.apk, but he did not keys

Comment: Looks like they're in that LM.apk file. It's an .apk because you gave it that extension... Why you say there are no keys? Did you try to use that file to retreive the keys and it fails? If so, what's the error?

Comment: You wrote a keystore file named LM.apk. Then you exported your application to a file with the exact same name. I would guess perhaps you overwrote the keystore file with the APK.

Comment: I can create a key using the debug keys ? I lost my key store ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're are misundersting the keystore :

- The keystore is a file which identify you (to securize your release), don't name it *.apk, it's not your application build
- You can store as many key in your keystore, one for each application you want to sign with

So you just have to create a first key on your keystore by providing an alias and a password

Then you'll have 1 password for opening your keystore and one for signing with the desired key (alias)

Comment: where is my water ??!! I am angry. somebody is stealing my water!

Comment: @MaxUsanin wow dude, really... *"You wrote a keystore file named LM.apk. Then you exported your application to a file with the exact same name. I would guess perhaps **you overwrote the keystore file with the APK**."*

Comment: The keys are wraped up in the keystore

Comment: @Plumillon Forge  How can I retrieve it from .apk  if it's wrapped?

Comment: Please read m0skit0 comment, you overwrote your keystore with your apk, your keystore is lost

Comment: Too bad, I sent an application ... and I can not now upgrade. Thank you explained to ...